# CSS Transitions for dynamic grid template columns

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-grid

I have a project where it requires dynamically changing the `grid-column` (Which I have achieved in the following link: https://codepen.io/DemogorGod/pen/oNMVvMV

[image: App image: dynamic cols with a trigger button. stage: 1]

[image: App image: dynamic cols with a trigger button. stage: 2]

I need to add a transition to the grid where once the button is clicked the two columns transition with ease...

I am hoping that there is a purly a CSS solution to this, however, if other solutions exist I am willing to implement them.

If it makes any difference I am using Vue.js...

Answer (score 2):

with the help from this [cool website](https://web.dev/css-animated-grid-layouts/), I found out that just animable are just `grid-template-columns`, not `grid-columns`. With that info, I just changed logic in your css code - toggling `grid-template-columns` in `.grid-container`. So you don't anymore need css code for items, you just update parent:

```css
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

a,
button {
  color: #4fc08d;
}

button {
  background: none;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-radius: 2em;
  font: inherit;
  padding: 0.75em 2em;
  width: 200px;
}

.grid_container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  margin: 10px 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s
}

.reverse {
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
}

.grid_side_one {
  border: #FBBD84 solid 1px;
}

.grid_side_two {
  border: #0D5FFF solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div id="app">
  <h5>
    Hello World
  </h5>
  <p>
    Dynamic grid with transitions
  </p>
  <button @click="toggle">
      Toggle Cols
    </button>
  <div class="grid_container" :class="ToggleCols ? 'reverse' : ''">
    <div class="grid_side_one">
      Left Side
    </div>
    <div class="grid_side_two">
      Rigth Side
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    Toggle: {{ ToggleCols }}
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>
<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        ToggleCols: true
      }
    },
    methods: {
      toggle() {
        this.ToggleCols = !this.ToggleCols
      }
    }
  })
</script>

</html>
```